SignalR : How to send message in chunks if size is more
I'm using SignalR to send messages from my .net core application to Angular front end. Sometimes the message size can be more than MaximumReceiveMessageSize configured. In this case what is the optimal way to handle message sending.

Do not send the payload itself, just send a signal. On the client side just load the full data from the server after receiving this signal.

Thanks for the response, My issue is if the payload size is more than configured size, my functionality breaks. Due to performance issue I've to limit per message size.

You can configure your message size on the server with: builder.Services.Configure<HubOptions>(options => {     options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024; }); But that is a static size. I think its not possible to do it on per request basis.

To Summarize:
The default maximum message is 32KB. To increase that use:
builder.Services.Configure<HubOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024;
})

Suggestion: Just send signals with Ids and get the full data by calling the server after receiving these Ids.
Its not possible to increase or decrease these size on a request base.
